# Get a List of non-inheritet connectionstrings in C#

Tags: iis, web-config, connection-string

I have an IIS (>7) with two applications `/foo` and `/foo/bar`. Both have several connectionstrings and I need to get a list of all connectionstrings of `/foo/bar` that are not inherited from `/foo`. I use `System.Web.Configuration` for some tasks and it would be cool to find a way to utilizing that classes here too. Any ideas?

I cannot read the web.config directly because the `connectionStrings`-section is protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found an solution.

```
var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(i_applicationVirtualPath);
if (config != null) {
    ConnectionStringsSection connectionStringSection = config.ConnectionStrings;
    ConnectionStringSettingsCollection connectionStringsCollection =
                connectionStringSection.ConnectionStrings;

    foreach (var settingObject in connectionStringsCollection) {
        ConnectionStringSettings setting = settingObject as ConnectionStringSettings;
        if (setting.ElementInformation.IsPresent) {
            // This connectionstring is in the corresponding web.config
        }
    }
}
```

This code detects only the connectionstrings I was looking for and is able to read transparently through the encryption. This should also work well for other configuration sections as well ...